# How to launch Steam in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: steam

I have installed Steam in Ubuntu 12.10, but I cannot figure out which icon to use to start Steam. How can I find the icon and launch Steam?

Answer (score 1):

Press the windows/super key than type in "steam" and it should show up.